# Javascript university task

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hello I have a task to make two colored tables, the first one must look like this:

[image]

and I've completed it via script:

```
n =10;
document.write("<table>");
for (i =1; i <n; i++)
{
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (j =1; j <=n; j++)
    {
        if (j <=i)
            s ="class ='r1'";
        else
            s ="class ='r2'";
        document.write("<td " + s + "> </td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

The second one must look like this:

[image]

and I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: This one also works: `if((j+i+1)%3 == 1)` Or there can be a counter which will be resetted when reacing 3, anyway the key to handle this task is to use division by 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern seems simple enough – **every 3rd cell** in a row is purple. The pattern also continues to the next line directly, so you could use `k % 3` where *k* is the total number of cells already drawn.

Comment: Although there is another answer with direct code, your one describes the way how it works, so I choose it as the solution, anyway much thanks for all who responded.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick

```js
n = 10; var c=1;
document.write("<table>");
for (i =1; i <=n; i++)
{
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (j =1; j <=n; j++)
    {
        c += 1;
        if ((c % 3) == 0)
            s ="class ='r1'";
        else
            s ="class ='r2'";
        document.write("<td " + s + "> </td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

```css
table td{
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.r1{
  background-color: pink;
}
.r2{
  background-color: blue;
}
```